# Unfound DefaultSource when connecting MongoDB with PySpark in PyCharm

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark, pyspark, pycharm

the following error returned when I am connecting MongoDB with PySpark in PyCharm.

"java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource. Please find packages at http://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html"

Python: 3.6.0

Spark:  2.2.0

Mongo-Spark connector:  mongo-spark-connector_2.11-2.2.0.jar

code is as followers:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Python Spark SQL basic example") \
        .config("spark.mongodb.input.uri", "mongodb://127.0.0.1/local.users") \
        .getOrCreate()

spark.conf.set("spark.jars", "/ExternalJar/mongo-spark-connector_2.11-2.2.0.jar")

df_users = spark.read.format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource")\
    .option("uri", "mongodb://127.0.0.1/local.users")\
    .load()
```

Comment: SparkSession is a singleton - so setting a config after its created won't work.

Comment: Thanks Ross.   I also tried to add it in .config("spark.jars", "../*.jar") in SparkSession builder on first line,  still doesn't work.